# Windows CE 6 Application Settings

Tags: .net, windows-ce, application-settings

I am new to Windows Mobile and working with CE6.  Are Application Settings an option like in standard WinForms?  I can't seem to find out anything.  What are my options for using local settings in WinCE6?

Answer (score 1):

Windows CE / Windows Mobile applications do not use app.config/web.config like desktop app or web sites. But you can implement the same logic, loading parameters during application start for example.

Basically, you have a file (often xml file) storing those parameters and your code will have to read them. You can do what you want.

Sample: http://developers.de/blogs/andreas_lehmann/archive/2009/05/26/a-simple-implementation-of-config-files-for-windows-mobile.aspx